# Не работает счетчик товаров на чистом JS

Tags: javascript

Пробовал через `id`, но данный метод не подойдет. Ведь счетчиков может быть множество. Попытался через поиск по классам, тоже пока не выходит. Нужна ваша помощь на чистом `JS`. Не могу понять саму суть, чтобы увеличение товаров работала отдельно для каждой карточки, наверное нужно использовать `this` или цикл `foreach` для обработки каждого элемента, пока ещё путаюсь в этом.

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector('product__col-wrap');
var countInput = document.getElementsByClassName('product__col');
var minus = document.getElementsByClassName('sprite-minus');
var plus = document.getElementsByClassName('sprite-plus');
var units = countInput.value.replace(/\d/g, '');

plus.onclick = function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  countInput.value = parseInt(countInput.value) + 1 + units;
};

minus.onclick = function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  if (parseInt(countInput.value) > 1) {
    countInput.value = parseInt(countInput.value) - 1 + units;
  }
};
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="product__col-wrap" id="product__col-wrap">
  <img src="http://cdn.axar.az/2017/04/15/pizza1.jpg" />
  <a class="sprite-minus" id="minus" href="">-</a>
  <input class="product__col" id="count" type="number" value="2">
  <a class="sprite-plus" id="plus" href="">+</a>
</div>
<div class="product__col-wrap" id="product__col-wrap">
  <img src="http://cdn.axar.az/2017/04/15/pizza1.jpg" />
  <a class="sprite-minus" id="minus" href="">-</a>
  <input class="product__col" id="count" type="number" value="2">
  <a class="sprite-plus" id="plus" href="">+</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лично я бы реализовал так. Не надо использовать ссылки там, где ссылки не нужны. Ссылка это ссылка и использовать надо как ссылку.

Да и еще, очень важное... `ID`- должен быть на странице единственным и уникальным... Двух `ID` У одного элемента быть не может. И одинаковых `ID` у разных элементов тоже

```js
var countInput = document.getElementsByClassName('product__col');
var minus = document.getElementsByClassName('sprite-minus');
var plus = document.getElementsByClassName('sprite-plus');

/* почему  у forEach((s, i) два аргумента. аргумент S это аналог THIS, который 
в данном примере не нужен, а вторым аргументом является INDEX элемента, которым
мы и определяем при нажатии какого элемента значение какого надо изменить
*/
[...document.querySelectorAll('.product__col-wrap')].forEach((s, i) => {

  minus[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if ((countInput[i].innerHTML) * 1 >= 1) {
      countInput[i].innerHTML = (countInput[i].innerHTML) * 1 - 1;
    }
  });

  plus[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    countInput[i].innerHTML = (countInput[i].innerHTML) * 1 + 1;
  })
})
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 200px;
  display: block;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="product__col-wrap">
  <span class="sprite-minus">-</span>
  <span class="product__col">2</span>
  <span class="sprite-plus">+</span>
</div>
<div class="product__col-wrap">
  <span class="sprite-minus">-</span>
  <span class="product__col">2</span>
  <span class="sprite-plus">+</span>
</div>
<div class="product__col-wrap">
  <span class="sprite-minus">-</span>
  <!--зачем использовать  input  type="number" если делаем счетчик кастомный?-->
  <span class="product__col">2</span>
  <span class="sprite-plus">+</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо за помощь. 
теперь остается добавить  на кнопку "-"
 if(parseInt(countInput.value) > 1) 
чтобы не было отрицательных значений

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!

Comment: Глянь исправил...

Comment: Это просто идеально :)) я просто так написал, что осталось-то по мелочи добавить. Очень выручили меня :) ещё раз огромное спасибо